# Is there an AI, Machine, or Automated Theorem Prover that builds source code from input?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I think my title is quite succinct.  Is there an AI, Machine, or Automated Theorem Prover (ATP) that builds source code from input? A very simple idea of what I'm getting at is this "Hey AI/Machine/ATP, please build a 'hello world' source code."

1. If not source code, what about creating output for LLVM IR, Java Bytecode, or MSIL?

Comment: it's called programmer and the input is coffee

Comment: @JSelser This is a serious question.

Comment: Coq is synthetizing Ocaml programs

Comment: From....what kind of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So last week I sat in on a lecture that answered my question.  What I am looking for is [Program Synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis).

While it doesn't do exactly as I am imagining, "Hey AI/Machine/ATP, build me a "hello world" program"  To simply quote Wikipedia:

```
Program synthesis is a special form of automatic programming that is most
often paired with a technique for formal verification. The goal is to 
construct automatically a program that provably satisfies a given high-level 
specification.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way a general program can be generated from a verbal description of the problem. The language (or machine code) your targeting doesn't make a difference, here.

You can easily write a program that emits a "Hello World" source in any programming language you like on being input "Please write 'Hello World' in C++." very easily. But then it can do nothing else, just the stuff you hard coded.

## Genetic programming

There is a branch of AI/Computer Science that is about *optimizing* or even generating from scratch programs that solve particular tasks well.

A popular approach is [genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming), where the program code evolves over several generations and is subject to mutation, selection and cross-breeding.

But for all this to work, you already have to describe your task formally, and the optimization is only about discovering a program that performs this task well. The problem of generating from a verbal description a formal description of a programming problem (which itself amounts to some form of programming) is not yet solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Not true.  I studied the problem starting in June 1975 and March 1977 I discovered 8 general Rules of Inference for synthesizing computer programs.  The algorithm continues to evolve.  See http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01363 .  Nobody will publish it because computer science academic publishing is an Old Boy's Club that only accepts paper from college professors.  Look at any academic journal and you'll see that every paper is by a professor - or a researcher for a rich company or university e.g. SRI.